# Better way to write this code? 3D position update of an object

Tags: python, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have an array for the position of the particle in cartesian coordinates and velocity in 3D. So that position[0] represents the x component of the position and so on. I'm curious if there is a better way to write this code, maybe shorter, maybe faster.

`

```
def update_position(self):
self.position[0] = self.position[0] + self.velocity[0] * self.tick     # x coordinate update
self.position[1] = self.position[1] + self.velocity[1] * self.tick     # y coordinate update
self.position[2] = self.position[2] + self.velocity[2] * self.tick     # z coordinate update
...
```

`

Comment: you could create a particle class in which x, y, and z are properties of a particle object, using the @property decorator.  but really there is not a single "right" way to do it.  you can do it in different ways depending on your preference

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_position(self):
    for i in range(3):
        self.position[i] += self.velocity[i] * self.tick
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the numpy library. It's a lot faster and easier to use. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
import numpy as np
...
def __init__(self):
  self.position = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
  self.velocity = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
...
self.position += self.velocity * self.tick
```